# How to count all comments to a Instagram profile?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Trying to working with some API's. Didnt find out how to count all comments were was posted to a custom Instagram profile. How to do it?

And also, there is no some extended analytics/statistics? Like YouTube API have, gross/loss followers, likes periods etc.

Comment: We use selenium on cucumber/capybara (Ruby) to infer some semantic data from html tags. But they are totally for test purposes. Comments are in list in instagram so you get the list size using acceptance test automation tools

Comment: So you want to say, there is no way to get this info by civilazated methods like API? :)

Comment: Of course that can be. However that's the only method I have experienced so far.. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few easy ways to do this -- if you're more comfortable working in Excel, you can easily export your Instagram analytics to Excel and isolate for comments there.

I think this tool comes with a free trial: http://www.crowdbabble.com/blog/export-your-instagram-analytics-to-excelcsv-reports/